# How to give drop down for parameters like virtual networks, storage accounts in Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I want to provision resources in Azure using ARM where user can select the required input parameters like Vnet or Function app that are already provisioned.
Just like AWS have parameter types such as **AWS::EC2::VPC::Id** to list down the VPC available in a region. For AWS references https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-the-new-cloudformation-parameter-types/

Is there something similar we can do in azure too.

Answer (score 1):

Similar, yes, the same no...  You can author a ui definition file that will allow you to restrict input.  For some resources there are controls you can leverage but there's also the capability to write a control that uses semi-custom logic (that could call an Azure API to list skus for example).

This is about the ui defintion:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-functions

And you can bundle it with a deployment template like this:

https://preview.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template/uri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2F100-marketplace-sample%2Fazuredeploy.json/createUIDefinitionUri/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2FAzure%2Fazure-quickstart-templates%2Fmaster%2F100-marketplace-sample%2FcreateUiDefinition.json

The feature is in preview right now, so you need to use preview.portal.azure.com instead of portal.azure.com but rollout will finish in a few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in ARM Templates. If you would be doing managed applications with arm templates you'd have some of the pickers (very limited set), but with regular arm templates you cant do that. you can create a powershell script that would mimic that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is (now, maybe not when this question was asked?) possible by using the [Microsoft.Solutions.ResourceSelector UI element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/microsoft-solutions-resourceselector).